# Разве Incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c, указатели, структуры, объявление

Приведу отрывок:

```
// Data model
typedef struct {
    struct student *next;
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int age;
} student;

// Smth like constructor
student frst = {NULL, -1, "_SERVICE_ELEM", 0};
student *first = &frst, *last = &frst;

// Free memory recursively
void cleanup(student *start)
{
    if (start->next != NULL) {
        cleanup(start->next);
    }
    printf("Cleaned id: %d name: %s\n", start->id, start->name);
    free(start);
    start = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    //...

    cleanup(first);

    return 0;
}
```

Это что-то вроде вектора, каждый элемент которого, содержит информацию о студенте и указатель на следующий элемент. Я привожу для примера только функцию очистки памяти, так как во всех остальных случаях получаю предупреждения подобного содержания. А именно:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Stack (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\Code\C\Vector\main.c||In function 'cleanup':|
D:\Code\C\Vector\main.c|21|warning: passing argument 1 of 'cleanup' from incompatible pointer type|
```

Вызвано строкой:

```
cleanup(start->next);
```

На сколько я понимаю, это вызвано тем, что поле `next` структуры `student` объявлено как `struct student *next` а тип аргумента `student *start`. Но почему типы указателей прям-таки `incompatible`, если всё работает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В этом объявлении

```
typedef struct {
    struct student *next;
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int age;
} student;
```

Объявляются два типа.

Первый тип определяется для безымянной структуры, которой с помощью спецификатора типа `typedef` назначается имя `student`.

Второй тип объявляется в этом объявлении члена данных безымянной структуры

```
struct student *next;
```

Здесь объявляется неполный тип `struct student`. Он не полный, потому что структура `struct student` не определена, а только объявлена.

Согласно стандарту C (6.7.2.3 Tags)

> 8 If a type specifier of the form

```
struct-or-union identifier
```

> occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and no other
>   declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible, then **it declares an
>   incomplete structure or union type**, and declares the identifier as the
>   tag of that type

Итак, объявлены две структуры: безымянная, которой присвоен алиас `student`, и структура `stuct student`.

`student` и `struct student` находятся в двух различных пространствах имен. Они не конфликтуют, так как имени структуры должно предшествовать ключевое слово `struct`.

Чтобы было более ясно, то когда компилятор анадизирует объявление безымянной структуры и доходит до объявления члена данных `next`

```
typedef struct {
    struct student *next;
    //...
```

то он имя `struct student` встречает впервые. Так как ранее это имя не было еще объявлено, то компилятор считает, что это объявление имени нового типа. Это имя типа комптютер никак не может связать с объявлением безымянной структуры. Он даже еще не знает, какой алиас будет присвоен этой безымянной структуре, ведь никто вам не мешает далее по завершению объявления безымянной структуры написать, к примеру

```
typedef struct {
    struct student *next;
    //...
} professor;
  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Поэтому компилятор и считает эти два объявления, объявление безымянной структуры и структуры `struct student`, различными.

Итак, вы объявили функцию как

```
void cleanup(student *start);
```

то есть она принимает указатель на тип `student`, А в теле самой функции вы рекурсивно вызываете ее саму, передавая в качестве аргумента указатель типа `struct student *`.

```
cleanup(start->next);
```

Компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке, так как, действительно, эти типы не совместимы. Более того, компилятор даже не знает определения структуры `strut student`.

Чтобы исправить ошибку, вам достаточно написать

```
typedef struct student {
    struct student *next;
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int age;
} student;
```

Тогда имя `student` будет алиасом для `struct student` и член данных `next`
 будет иметь тип указателя на объекты этой же структуры.

Comment: Как всегда отличный ответ, спасибо

Comment: @DimTeam Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется, incompatible.

Ваше поле-указатель `next` объявлено как указатель на некий неполный тип `struct student`. Такого типа в вашей программе больше нигде не упоминается и что это за тип - не ясно. Он так и остается неполным.

В дальнейшем вы в

```
cleanup(start->next);
```

пытаетесь этот указатель передавать в качестве аргумента для параметра типа `student *`. А это совсем другой тип. `student *` - это указатель на вашу структуру. `struct student *` - это указатель на какую-то неизвестную структуру. Это два совершенно не связанных друг с другом типа. Потому они и incompatible.

А то, что "все работает" уже к языку С никакого отношения не имеет. Программа не является корректной программой на языке С.

Вы, очевидно, пытались сделать что-то такое

```
typedef struct student student;

struct student {
    student *next;
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int age;
};
```

или

```
typedef struct student {
    struct student *next;
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int age;
} student;
```

(выберите, какой вариант вам больше по душе).

И вообще, объявлять структуры без указания тэга в С - сомнительная практика. Если вы предпочитаете typedef-ить struct-типы, то давайте им один и тот же идентификатор и в качестве тэга, и в качестве "короткого" имени типа.